# Google Analaytics and multilanguage site

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I have a multilanguage site in PHP but I don´t have subdirectories
for the different languages. All the views are translated based on a PHP session

so instead of having mysite.com/es/about I just have mysite.com/about
and based on a PHP session I display  the content in one language or another.

how can I deal with google analytics? is there a way to set a pageLanguage?

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'XXX');
gtag('pageLanguage', '<?php echo $language?>');
```

is this correct? thank you

Comment: i would almost set it as a custom dimension https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: Since it's a page-level dimension, and you're limited to 20 custom dimensions, maybe content grouping is an alternative as these typically tend to be under used but fit very well the content scope: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7475939?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

As is commented, the best option is to add the language as Custom Dimension, to do it is necessary to add the custom dimension before the pageview is sent.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag( 'set' , {'dimension1' : "<?php echo $language?>"} ); // change the index of the dimension
gtag('config', 'XXX');
```

This set will add this CD on all the hit of the load page, due the language is a page information, the recommended scope is the hit level.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en

Comment: and the name has to be dimension1? can I change it to anything I want? also.. do I have to define it first in analytics? thank you!

Comment: Hi, yes, you have to define it on Google Analytics on the Property Setting ->Custom Dimensions tab (almost on the bottom), once you create a new custom dimension, he will give you the index ( if you didn't got any will be the dimension1) .